# Require 'cannot load such file'. Pushed my directory into the $: array

Tags: ruby, directory, require

I solved my problem through

```
require_relative
require './whateverfileiplannedtorequire'
load 'whateverfileiplannedtorequire'
```

but I am trying to get `require` to work without the `./` at the beginning as is advertised in [the Beginning Ruby book](http://beginningruby.org/). I hoped pushing my `CWD` into the `$:` array would fix this, but it didn't. How would I manage to get `require` to work as shown in the book?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$:.unshift "/my/directory"
```

For example to add the current directory (where the source file is) to the load path:

```
$:.unshift File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
```